# Convert PyGame game into .APK file

Tags: python, pygame, apk

I have just made a game in python using PyGame in python. I want to convert it into an .APK file (basically an android application). How do I do this?

I tried searching on youtube but all of these videos talk only about kivy and not pygame. Is there something that I'm missing? I asked chatGPT and it replies some random things like "pip install pygame2apk".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey i think there are several ways to convert a python file to an apk.
In an old project I've used Kivy link: https://kivy.org/.

Here the link how to install it: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/installation.html

I hope this post helps you out

Comment: I'm still confused a little should I reprogram the thing in kivy (I used pygame in my project)?Or is there something im not understanding about kivy/ missing

Comment: 1. Download kivi

2. Prepare your python file so it is compatible with kivy

3. Use Builddozer provided by kivy create a .spec file

4. Build and finally deploy

you can always read the documentation

Comment: What do you exactly mean by compatible with kivy. And thanks for taking time to reply.